# Python3 float to int from load file

Tags: python

I am beginner in python and I have a file with e.g data:

```
123.141212412
123124.5436456
13123.123546
```

I am trying to convert it to inteeger.

My idea was load file to a list and format the records. But it throws an error.
I did:

```
file.write(str(format(list1,'.0f')))
```

Comment: You'll need to provide more detail in your question. Please post your full code and the error message you're receiving. It may be helpful for you to read: [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

You may perform the same in this manner :

```
file = open('test.txt', 'r') 

# List to hold the numbers
x = []

# end = split at \n because \n is read in lines too
for line in file.read().split('\n'):
    
    # Type casting to int
    int_num = int(float(line))
    
    # saving the int part of the data in list
    x.append(int_num) 
    
    # printing the int part
    print(int_num)
```

Comment: If it helped you then please accept the answer by checking the green tick below the voting section. If you need any explanation or followup question, please comment.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly apply `format` on a `list`, you have to loop through your list to do so, like this:

```py
for number in list1:
    file.write(format(number, ".0f") + "\n")
```

Of course, this assumes `file` exists and have been correctly defined, like this:

```py
file = open("my_filename", "w")
```